# Looking to convert complex json schema to C# class however API returned types not always matching

Tags: c#, json

I am working on a C# program to get API json data using the following Json C# class (created from API json resource page using json2csharp) however the API itself is at times sending decimals such as "0.0" instead of expected integer "0" which throws exceptions when I attempt to populate the class using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() method. I can of course manually change each variable or use dynamic variables however am looking to avoid this, should I attempt to (cast) the variable the API is sending when the class is "set" the variables or is there a better solution?

JSON C# Class, Root is the main class here:

```
 // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Position
    {
        public int shortQuantity { get; set; }
        public int averagePrice { get; set; }
        public int currentDayProfitLoss { get; set; }
        public int currentDayProfitLossPercentage { get; set; }
        public int longQuantity { get; set; }
        public int settledLongQuantity { get; set; }
        public int settledShortQuantity { get; set; }
        public int agedQuantity { get; set; }
        public string instrument { get; set; }
        public int marketValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class CancelTime
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public bool shortFormat { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderLegCollection
    {
        public string orderLegType { get; set; }
        public int legId { get; set; }
        public string instrument { get; set; }
        public string instruction { get; set; }
        public string positionEffect { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string quantityType { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReplacingOrderCollection
    {
    }

    public class ChildOrderStrategy
    {
    }

    public class OrderStrategy
    {
        public string session { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string orderType { get; set; }
        public CancelTime cancelTime { get; set; }
        public string complexOrderStrategyType { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public int filledQuantity { get; set; }
        public int remainingQuantity { get; set; }
        public string requestedDestination { get; set; }
        public string destinationLinkName { get; set; }
        public string releaseTime { get; set; }
        public int stopPrice { get; set; }
        public string stopPriceLinkBasis { get; set; }
        public string stopPriceLinkType { get; set; }
        public int stopPriceOffset { get; set; }
        public string stopType { get; set; }
        public string priceLinkBasis { get; set; }
        public string priceLinkType { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public string taxLotMethod { get; set; }
        public List<OrderLegCollection> orderLegCollection { get; set; }
        public int activationPrice { get; set; }
        public string specialInstruction { get; set; }
        public string orderStrategyType { get; set; }
        public int orderId { get; set; }
        public bool cancelable { get; set; }
        public bool editable { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string enteredTime { get; set; }
        public string closeTime { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public int accountId { get; set; }
        public List<string> orderActivityCollection { get; set; }
        public List<ReplacingOrderCollection> replacingOrderCollection { get; set; }
        public List<ChildOrderStrategy> childOrderStrategies { get; set; }
        public string statusDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class InitialBalances
    {
        public int accruedInterest { get; set; }
        public int availableFundsNonMarginableTrade { get; set; }
        public int bondValue { get; set; }
        public int buyingPower { get; set; }
        public int cashBalance { get; set; }
        public int cashAvailableForTrading { get; set; }
        public int cashReceipts { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingBuyingPower { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingBuyingPowerCall { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingEquityCall { get; set; }
        public int equity { get; set; }
        public int equityPercentage { get; set; }
        public int liquidationValue { get; set; }
        public int longMarginValue { get; set; }
        public int longOptionMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int longStockValue { get; set; }
        public int maintenanceCall { get; set; }
        public int maintenanceRequirement { get; set; }
        public int margin { get; set; }
        public int marginEquity { get; set; }
        public int moneyMarketFund { get; set; }
        public int mutualFundValue { get; set; }
        public int regTCall { get; set; }
        public int shortMarginValue { get; set; }
        public int shortOptionMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int shortStockValue { get; set; }
        public int totalCash { get; set; }
        public bool isInCall { get; set; }
        public int unsettledCash { get; set; }
        public int pendingDeposits { get; set; }
        public int marginBalance { get; set; }
        public int shortBalance { get; set; }
        public int accountValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class CurrentBalances
    {
        public int accruedInterest { get; set; }
        public int cashBalance { get; set; }
        public int cashReceipts { get; set; }
        public int longOptionMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int liquidationValue { get; set; }
        public int longMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int moneyMarketFund { get; set; }
        public int savings { get; set; }
        public int shortMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int pendingDeposits { get; set; }
        public int availableFunds { get; set; }
        public int availableFundsNonMarginableTrade { get; set; }
        public int buyingPower { get; set; }
        public int buyingPowerNonMarginableTrade { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingBuyingPower { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingBuyingPowerCall { get; set; }
        public int equity { get; set; }
        public int equityPercentage { get; set; }
        public int longMarginValue { get; set; }
        public int maintenanceCall { get; set; }
        public int maintenanceRequirement { get; set; }
        public int marginBalance { get; set; }
        public int regTCall { get; set; }
        public int shortBalance { get; set; }
        public int shortMarginValue { get; set; }
        public int shortOptionMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int sma { get; set; }
        public int mutualFundValue { get; set; }
        public int bondValue { get; set; }
        public bool isInCall { get; set; }
        public int stockBuyingPower { get; set; }
        public int optionBuyingPower { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectedBalances
    {
        public int accruedInterest { get; set; }
        public int cashBalance { get; set; }
        public int cashReceipts { get; set; }
        public int longOptionMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int liquidationValue { get; set; }
        public int longMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int moneyMarketFund { get; set; }
        public int savings { get; set; }
        public int shortMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int pendingDeposits { get; set; }
        public int availableFunds { get; set; }
        public int availableFundsNonMarginableTrade { get; set; }
        public int buyingPower { get; set; }
        public int buyingPowerNonMarginableTrade { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingBuyingPower { get; set; }
        public int dayTradingBuyingPowerCall { get; set; }
        public int equity { get; set; }
        public int equityPercentage { get; set; }
        public int longMarginValue { get; set; }
        public int maintenanceCall { get; set; }
        public int maintenanceRequirement { get; set; }
        public int marginBalance { get; set; }
        public int regTCall { get; set; }
        public int shortBalance { get; set; }
        public int shortMarginValue { get; set; }
        public int shortOptionMarketValue { get; set; }
        public int sma { get; set; }
        public int mutualFundValue { get; set; }
        public int bondValue { get; set; }
        public bool isInCall { get; set; }
        public int stockBuyingPower { get; set; }
        public int optionBuyingPower { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public securitiesAccount securitiesAccount { get; set; }
    }

    public class securitiesAccount
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string accountId { get; set; }
        public int roundTrips { get; set; }
        public bool isDayTrader { get; set; }
        public bool isClosingOnlyRestricted { get; set; }
        public List<Position> positions { get; set; }
        public List<OrderStrategy> orderStrategies { get; set; }
        public InitialBalances initialBalances { get; set; }
        public CurrentBalances currentBalances { get; set; }
        public ProjectedBalances projectedBalances { get; set; }
    }
```

Expected JSON I should be receiving per API documentation (however am receiving decimals in some cases where I am expecting an integer or vice versa):

```html
//Account:
{
  "securitiesAccount": "The type <securitiesAccount> has the following subclasses [MarginAccount, CashAccount] descriptions are listed below"
}

//The class <securitiesAccount> has the 
//following subclasses: 
//-MarginAccount
//-CashAccount
//JSON for each are listed below: 

//MarginAccount:
{
  "type": "'CASH' or 'MARGIN'",
  "accountId": "string",
  "roundTrips": 0,
  "isDayTrader": false,
  "isClosingOnlyRestricted": false,
  "positions": [
    {
      "shortQuantity": 0,
      "averagePrice": 0,
      "currentDayProfitLoss": 0,
      "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": 0,
      "longQuantity": 0,
      "settledLongQuantity": 0,
      "settledShortQuantity": 0,
      "agedQuantity": 0,
      "instrument": "The type <Instrument> has the following subclasses [Equity, FixedIncome, MutualFund, CashEquivalent, Option] descriptions are listed below\"",
      "marketValue": 0
    }
  ],
  "orderStrategies": [
    {
      "session": "'NORMAL' or 'AM' or 'PM' or 'SEAMLESS'",
      "duration": "'DAY' or 'GOOD_TILL_CANCEL' or 'FILL_OR_KILL'",
      "orderType": "'MARKET' or 'LIMIT' or 'STOP' or 'STOP_LIMIT' or 'TRAILING_STOP' or 'MARKET_ON_CLOSE' or 'EXERCISE' or 'TRAILING_STOP_LIMIT' or 'NET_DEBIT' or 'NET_CREDIT' or 'NET_ZERO'",
      "cancelTime": {
        "date": "string",
        "shortFormat": false
      },
      "complexOrderStrategyType": "'NONE' or 'COVERED' or 'VERTICAL' or 'BACK_RATIO' or 'CALENDAR' or 'DIAGONAL' or 'STRADDLE' or 'STRANGLE' or 'COLLAR_SYNTHETIC' or 'BUTTERFLY' or 'CONDOR' or 'IRON_CONDOR' or 'VERTICAL_ROLL' or 'COLLAR_WITH_STOCK' or 'DOUBLE_DIAGONAL' or 'UNBALANCED_BUTTERFLY' or 'UNBALANCED_CONDOR' or 'UNBALANCED_IRON_CONDOR' or 'UNBALANCED_VERTICAL_ROLL' or 'CUSTOM'",
      "quantity": 0,
      "filledQuantity": 0,
      "remainingQuantity": 0,
      "requestedDestination": "'INET' or 'ECN_ARCA' or 'CBOE' or 'AMEX' or 'PHLX' or 'ISE' or 'BOX' or 'NYSE' or 'NASDAQ' or 'BATS' or 'C2' or 'AUTO'",
      "destinationLinkName": "string",
      "releaseTime": "string",
      "stopPrice": 0,
      "stopPriceLinkBasis": "'MANUAL' or 'BASE' or 'TRIGGER' or 'LAST' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'ASK_BID' or 'MARK' or 'AVERAGE'",
      "stopPriceLinkType": "'VALUE' or 'PERCENT' or 'TICK'",
      "stopPriceOffset": 0,
      "stopType": "'STANDARD' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'LAST' or 'MARK'",
      "priceLinkBasis": "'MANUAL' or 'BASE' or 'TRIGGER' or 'LAST' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'ASK_BID' or 'MARK' or 'AVERAGE'",
      "priceLinkType": "'VALUE' or 'PERCENT' or 'TICK'",
      "price": 0,
      "taxLotMethod": "'FIFO' or 'LIFO' or 'HIGH_COST' or 'LOW_COST' or 'AVERAGE_COST' or 'SPECIFIC_LOT'",
      "orderLegCollection": [
        {
          "orderLegType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
          "legId": 0,
          "instrument": "\"The type <Instrument> has the following subclasses [Equity, FixedIncome, MutualFund, CashEquivalent, Option] descriptions are listed below\"",
          "instruction": "'BUY' or 'SELL' or 'BUY_TO_COVER' or 'SELL_SHORT' or 'BUY_TO_OPEN' or 'BUY_TO_CLOSE' or 'SELL_TO_OPEN' or 'SELL_TO_CLOSE' or 'EXCHANGE'",
          "positionEffect": "'OPENING' or 'CLOSING' or 'AUTOMATIC'",
          "quantity": 0,
          "quantityType": "'ALL_SHARES' or 'DOLLARS' or 'SHARES'"
        }
      ],
      "activationPrice": 0,
      "specialInstruction": "'ALL_OR_NONE' or 'DO_NOT_REDUCE' or 'ALL_OR_NONE_DO_NOT_REDUCE'",
      "orderStrategyType": "'SINGLE' or 'OCO' or 'TRIGGER'",
      "orderId": 0,
      "cancelable": false,
      "editable": false,
      "status": "'AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER' or 'AWAITING_CONDITION' or 'AWAITING_MANUAL_REVIEW' or 'ACCEPTED' or 'AWAITING_UR_OUT' or 'PENDING_ACTIVATION' or 'QUEUED' or 'WORKING' or 'REJECTED' or 'PENDING_CANCEL' or 'CANCELED' or 'PENDING_REPLACE' or 'REPLACED' or 'FILLED' or 'EXPIRED'",
      "enteredTime": "string",
      "closeTime": "string",
      "tag": "string",
      "accountId": 0,
      "orderActivityCollection": [
        "\"The type <OrderActivity> has the following subclasses [Execution] descriptions are listed below\""
      ],
      "replacingOrderCollection": [
        {}
      ],
      "childOrderStrategies": [
        {}
      ],
      "statusDescription": "string"
    }
  ],
  "initialBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "availableFundsNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "buyingPower": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashAvailableForTrading": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPower": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPowerCall": 0,
    "dayTradingEquityCall": 0,
    "equity": 0,
    "equityPercentage": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarginValue": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "longStockValue": 0,
    "maintenanceCall": 0,
    "maintenanceRequirement": 0,
    "margin": 0,
    "marginEquity": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "regTCall": 0,
    "shortMarginValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "shortStockValue": 0,
    "totalCash": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "unsettledCash": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "marginBalance": 0,
    "shortBalance": 0,
    "accountValue": 0
  },
  "currentBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarketValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "savings": 0,
    "shortMarketValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "availableFunds": 0,
    "availableFundsNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "buyingPower": 0,
    "buyingPowerNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPower": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPowerCall": 0,
    "equity": 0,
    "equityPercentage": 0,
    "longMarginValue": 0,
    "maintenanceCall": 0,
    "maintenanceRequirement": 0,
    "marginBalance": 0,
    "regTCall": 0,
    "shortBalance": 0,
    "shortMarginValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "sma": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "stockBuyingPower": 0,
    "optionBuyingPower": 0
  },
  "projectedBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarketValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "savings": 0,
    "shortMarketValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "availableFunds": 0,
    "availableFundsNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "buyingPower": 0,
    "buyingPowerNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPower": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPowerCall": 0,
    "equity": 0,
    "equityPercentage": 0,
    "longMarginValue": 0,
    "maintenanceCall": 0,
    "maintenanceRequirement": 0,
    "marginBalance": 0,
    "regTCall": 0,
    "shortBalance": 0,
    "shortMarginValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "sma": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "stockBuyingPower": 0,
    "optionBuyingPower": 0
  }
}
```

For example if I run the code below, it throws an error since the API is sending me value 0.0 for "shortQuantity" inside the jsonSTRING (when it should be sending me an integer per API documentation). Any other types that match the object types of my class are filling appropriately.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass.Root>(jsonSTRING);
```

Also attempting to find how I can extract the data back out of the class into a table format once I store it in there.

Comment: Does the type of a single field change at random from request to request? Or is it always just a decimal (even though you expect an integer)? Either way, can you not just change the type to decimal?

Comment: It can vary from time to time and some of the variables aren’t always returned so they end up being null sometimes. I will try to change the type to decimal and run some tests. Would you know how I can take the class with variables and output all the class and subclass variables into a string or table to review it? Or alternatively directly convert the json string into a table/spreadsheet?